# State change after form submit gets reverted immediately in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state, dom-events

I have a simple react app that lists users from state. The code is as follows :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    users : [
      { name:'Ramu', age:23 },
      { name:'Somu', age:34 },
      { name:'Bheemu', age:45 }
    ]
  };

  addUser = (user, e) => {
    let users = Object.assign([], this.state.users);
    users.push(user)
    this.setState({
      users : users
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          { 
            this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
              return (<div>              
                { user.name } | {user.age}
                </div>)
            }) 
          }
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={this.addUser.bind(this, { name:'Sita', age:21 })}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            Age:
            <input type="text" />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

On submitting the form the user gets added but immediately page is reloaded and the new user gets removed from the state. Why is the new user getting removed?

Comment: put `e.preventDefault()` in `addUser` method.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need prevent default browser form submit. Add `e.preventDefault()` inside the `addUser` method. Default browser form submit reloads that page, so new `<App />` component gets created with its initial state and you loose the new data.